# Combining datasets with EXCEPT versus checking on IS NULL in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

I'm currently working my way through the *Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Database Development (MCTS Exam 70-433)* certification. In one of the earlier chapters on *Combining Datasets*, I came across the `EXCEPT` (and `INTERSECT`) commands. One example shows how to use `EXCEPT` to get all values from one table that doesn't have a related value in a second table like this:

```
SELECT EmployeeKey FROM DimEmployee
EXCEPT
SELECT EmployeeKey FROM FactResellerSales
```

The `EXCEPT` command was new to me, but with what I knew before today I would still easily solve the problem using a `LEFT JOIN` and check for `IS NULL` on the join constraint the following way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DimEmployee.EmployeeKey FROM DimEmployee
LEFT JOIN FactResellerSales ON FactResellerSales.EmployeeKey = DimEmployee.EmployeeKey
WHERE FactResellerSales.EmployeeKey IS NULL
```

Now I started to wonder which one of these have the best performance. I tried to study the query execution plans, but I'm not too good at reading those, so it didn't make me any wiser. For the query using `EXCEPT`, the plan looks like this:

```
|--Nested Loops(Left Anti Semi Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey], [Expr1006]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[DimEmployee].[IX_DimEmployee_SalesTerritoryKey]))
    |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
        |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[FactResellerSales].[IX_FactResellerSales_EmployeeKey]), SEEK:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[FactResellerSales].[EmployeeKey]=[AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

And for the one using the `LEFT JOIN` it looks like this:

```
|--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey]))
    |--Filter(WHERE:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[FactResellerSales].[EmployeeKey] IS NULL))
        |--Merge Join(Left Outer Join, MERGE:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey])=([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[FactResellerSales].[EmployeeKey]), RESIDUAL:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[FactResellerSales].[EmployeeKey]=[AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey]))
            |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[DimEmployee].[PK_DimEmployee_EmployeeKey]), ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([AdventureWorksDW2008].[dbo].[FactResellerSales].[IX_FactResellerSales_EmployeeKey]), ORDERED FORWARD)
```

The tables used in the query are from the *AdventureWorksDW2008* example database, so below I also include the create scripts for the two tables in case that is needed to answer the question correctly:

```
USE [AdventureWorksDW2008]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DimEmployee]    Script Date: 11/22/2010 20:30:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimEmployee](
    [EmployeeKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentEmployeeKey] [int] NULL,
    [EmployeeNationalIDAlternateKey] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ParentEmployeeNationalIDAlternateKey] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [SalesTerritoryKey] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NameStyle] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [HireDate] [date] NULL,
    [BirthDate] [date] NULL,
    [LoginID] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [MaritalStatus] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [EmergencyContactName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EmergencyContactPhone] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [SalariedFlag] [bit] NULL,
    [Gender] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [PayFrequency] [tinyint] NULL,
    [BaseRate] [money] NULL,
    [VacationHours] [smallint] NULL,
    [SickLeaveHours] [smallint] NULL,
    [CurrentFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SalesPersonFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [StartDate] [date] NULL,
    [EndDate] [date] NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DimEmployee_EmployeeKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimEmployee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DimEmployee_DimEmployee] FOREIGN KEY([ParentEmployeeKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimEmployee] ([EmployeeKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimEmployee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DimEmployee_DimEmployee]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimEmployee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DimEmployee_DimSalesTerritory] FOREIGN KEY([SalesTerritoryKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimSalesTerritory] ([SalesTerritoryKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimEmployee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DimEmployee_DimSalesTerritory]
GO
```

And the second table:

```
USE [AdventureWorksDW2008]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FactResellerSales]    Script Date: 11/22/2010 20:30:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales](
    [ProductKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderDateKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DueDateKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipDateKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResellerKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PromotionKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CurrencyKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalesTerritoryKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalesOrderNumber] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SalesOrderLineNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [RevisionNumber] [tinyint] NULL,
    [OrderQuantity] [smallint] NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [money] NULL,
    [ExtendedAmount] [money] NULL,
    [UnitPriceDiscountPct] [float] NULL,
    [DiscountAmount] [float] NULL,
    [ProductStandardCost] [money] NULL,
    [TotalProductCost] [money] NULL,
    [SalesAmount] [money] NULL,
    [TaxAmt] [money] NULL,
    [Freight] [money] NULL,
    [CarrierTrackingNumber] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [CustomerPONumber] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FactResellerSales_SalesOrderNumber_SalesOrderLineNumber] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SalesOrderNumber] ASC,
    [SalesOrderLineNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimCurrency] FOREIGN KEY([CurrencyKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimCurrency] ([CurrencyKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimCurrency]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimDate] FOREIGN KEY([OrderDateKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimDate] ([DateKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimDate1] FOREIGN KEY([DueDateKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimDate] ([DateKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimDate1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimDate2] FOREIGN KEY([ShipDateKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimDate] ([DateKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimDate2]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimEmployee] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimEmployee] ([EmployeeKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimEmployee]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimProduct] FOREIGN KEY([ProductKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimProduct] ([ProductKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimProduct]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimPromotion] FOREIGN KEY([PromotionKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimPromotion] ([PromotionKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimPromotion]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimReseller] FOREIGN KEY([ResellerKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimReseller] ([ResellerKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimReseller]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimSalesTerritory] FOREIGN KEY([SalesTerritoryKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimSalesTerritory] ([SalesTerritoryKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactResellerSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactResellerSales_DimSalesTerritory]
GO
```

This question is using a very specific example, but I'm also interested in general information about when/if it would be appropriate to use `EXCEPT` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` and check on `IS NULL`.

I also noticed, that if I tried running the 1st query with `INTERCEPT`, the equivalent in the 2nd query would be to use a standard `JOIN` and `SELECT DISTINCT DimEmployee.EmployeeKey` (and no `WHERE` clause at all). In this case however, the execution plan was exactly the same in the two cases.

***Update***
Minor update to the 2nd query (see revision history), which resulted in a bit more complex query plan for that one. I would guess that a bigger query plan indicates a less optimal query, but I'd still like this question to be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 queries will be different in cases where the LEFT JOIN gives multiple rows. That is, FactResellerSales is a child of DimEmployee with many rows per rows in DimEmployee. So you need DISTINCT as you noted for your JOIN example.

If you change the query to use NOT EXISTS you get the same plan (left anti semi join is typical for NOT EXISTS)

```
SELECT EmployeeKey
FROM DimEmployee DE 
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
        FactResellerSales FRS
    WHERE FRS.EmployeeKey = DE.EmployeeKey)
```

In addition and for the same reason, INTERSECT/EXISTS will most likely give the same plan.

It's another aspect to the `JOIN/EXISTS/IN` or `OUTER JOIN/NOT EXISTS/NOT IN` debates. INTERSECT/EXCEPT is a slightly more elegant construct of (NOT) EXISTS is you like

Edit:

There isn't an obvious question...

Personally, I don't use OUTER JOIN for "existence" checking: I use EXISTS or NOT EXISTS (or INTERSECT/EXCEPT if I remember) because it's more obvious what you're trying to do. AKA, if I don't need rows from the "outer" table, I don't use it to avoid having a DISTINCT.

There is no CASE to use OUTER JOIN/IS NULL IMHO *if* in this case. Of course, I use OUTER JOIN when needed: this answer is for one specific case only.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that the two queries were different. I'll update the query (and execution plans) so that the question is as "correct" as possible. I'll get back to you with some more comments after that.

Comment: you say `INTERSECT`/`EXCEPT` is slightly more elegant (which I totally agree with, it looks nicer and is easier to read). But does it also offer better performance than using `LEFT JOIN` as in my example (which should yield the same result set now that I added `DISTINCT to the query`)? And would this be the same in a general case, compared to my specific example?

Comment: just one more question so I'm sure I got it right: you say *The 2 queries will be different in cases where the LEFT JOIN gives multiple rows*. Is this because `EXCEPT` (as well as `INTERSECT` and `UNION`) automatically removes duplicate entries from the result set?

Comment: @Nailuj: No. Duplicate entries occur say if you have 3 rows in FactResellerSales for a given DimEmployee row. This is a result of how JOIN (the keyword, not the internal plan operator) works. INTERSECT/EXCEPT/EXISTS/NOT EXISTS/IN/NOT IN are not JOINs (again, ignoring how the internal plan operator) and do not de-duplicate because there are no duplicates to remove (in DimEmployee in this case)