# T-SQL: Where xxx IN temporary table

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, in-operator, temp-tables

I have a temp table and want to check in a where clause wether a certain id/string is contained in the temp table.

```
Select...
WHERE MyId  IN MyTempTable
```

I get a general error in MS SQL Management studio.

is the "In" operator not suited for temp tables?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE MyID IN (SELECT MyID
                  FROM MyTempTable)
```

I don't much like the IN operator, so I prefer this:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM MyTempTable
                WHERE MyTable.MyID = MyID)
```

But it's largely a matter of taste.

Comment: +1 you're correct because generally it's better for NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS which are quite different. So why not use EXISTS consistently? INTERSECT works too. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249891/combining-datasets-with-except-versus-checking-on-is-null-in-a-left-join/4249958#4249958) please

Comment: @gbn: As I said, it is largely a matter of taste, but my reasons are more based on my understanding of the relational model than just consistency. Firstly, `IN` is a bit of a wart in the language that is strictly unnecessary; anything that can be expressed using `(NOT) IN` has an equivalent `(NOT) EXISTS`. But also, it is a semantic oddity that doesn't hark from either the relational algebra or the relational calculus. It was plonked in there by SQL's designers for reasons I can't fathom. It must have been a big deal, though, since it is apparently the reason for the S in SQL ("Structured").

Comment: NOT IN does not equal NOT EXISTS hence my comment. A NULL in the NOT IN list will give no results. Why is "IN "there? I guess when ANSI was put together they took IN from one of the then current SQL dialects

Comment: @gbn: You are right, but I avoid nulls like the plague (atrocities like `NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', NULL)` being just one of many motivations), so I don't generally consider such scenarios in my thinking. Also, I wasn't referring to ANSI SQL, but the original design work that spawned those dialects.

Comment: @Lisa: The obvious way. If you can't figure it out, post another question with whatever code you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is slightly wrong.  You need to do:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ...
 WHERE MyId IN (SELECT MyId 
                  FROM MyTempTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` requires a list of specific items.  Tables generally have more than one field, how is it to know which field you mean?

You can use a subquery, `where field in (select whatever from #temp)`