# To take out those dept who has no employees assigned to it

Tags: sql, select

I want to write an sql query , and want to get the dept name from DEPT table who has no employees assigned in EMP table.

Table Structure:

```
EMP
EMPNO   ENAME    DEPTNO

DEPT
DEPTNO   DNAME
```

So I like to know those DEPT who has no employees association.

Comment: you may either use a left join and check for NULLs or you can use a sub query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's only *correct* with NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT D.DNAME
FROM DEPT D
WHERE
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMP E WHERE D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO)
```

or EXCEPT, more complex in this case

```
SELECT D.DNAME
FROM DEPT D
EXCEPT
SELECT D.DNAME
FROM DEPT D
JOIN 
EMP E WHERE D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO
```

Both should give the same plan (with a left anti semi join)

Notes on other answers:

- A LEFT JOIN will give one row per employee. You'd need DISTINCT. Which compromises the plan compared with NOT EXISTS
- NOT IN will give false results if there is an Employee who has no Department. NOT IN with a NULL in the list fails

So *generally* one should use NOT EXISTS or EXCEPT

Comment: Could you add info about which dbms you tried? On Oracle, the first query will generate an anti join (hash or nl depending on data distribution) whereas the second query causes results in two sorts.

Comment: @Ronnis: SQL server. Based on experience and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249891/combining-datasets-with-except-versus-checking-on-is-null-in-a-left-join/4249958#4249958

Answer (score 4):

```
select dname from dept where deptno not in (select deptno from emp)
```

Comment: Let's hope every employee has a department. CEO may not have a department and deptno could be NULL = fail...

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT D.DNAME
FROM DEPT D
LEFT JOIN EMP E ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO
WHERE E.DEPTNO IS NULL
```

**UPDATE:**

@bernd_k pointed out that `DISTINCT` is not necessary (*SELECT <strike>DISTINCT</strike> D.DNAME ...*) in this case - even without it no duplicate departments will be returned.

Comment: @bernd_k: you'd get one row per EMP. So you need DISTINCT. Which was added after on a quick update so does not show as an edit...

Comment: @gbn but those where excluded by the where clause. I get no duplicates for the unjoined departments. DISTINCT is not needed

Comment: @bernd_k: this is actually a special case. Generally, you usually need DISTINCT to compensate for multiple rows caused by the JOIN.

Comment: @gbn In those cases, when I only select columns from the left table I prefer the where in ... construct, to avoid DISTINCT

Comment: @gbn admitted, but the case to avoid distinct is the where x in (select y ...) case and that is reliable. Possible Nulls in subselect don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.DEPTNO
FROM EMP E
JOIN DEPT D ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO (+)
WHERE E.EMPNO IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select DName 
from DEPT
where DName NOT IN (Select Distinct EMP.DName from EMP);
```

Comment: "In" clause has the limit which vary around the different databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can select these departments from dept table whom numbers are not present in emp table:

```
SELECT dname
FROM dept 
WHERE deptno 
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT deptno 
FROM emp);
```

Comment: Please update with a short explanation for what your code does)

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie

Answer (score 0):

```
select  x.DEPTNO from dept x where x.DEPTNO not in 
(select d.DEPTNO from department d join
employee e where e.deptid=d.DEPTNO)
```

The sub query is used to get all the employees who are associated with a department:

```
select d.DEPTNO from department d join
employee e where e.deptid=d.DEPTNO
 and using select  x.DEPTNO from dept x where x.DEPTNO
```

`not in` will give the employees who do not belong to any department.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

The below is not using any except or not in and performance wise it is better

```
select d.dname 
from emp e right
join dept d on e.deptno=d.deptno
group by d.dname
having count(e.empno)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,NAME,SAL,DEPTNAME,DEPTID
FROM emp
FULL JOIN
DEPT
ON EMP.departmentid=DEPT.DEPTID
WHERE DEPTID IS NULL
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed answer rather than just a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Find department_id for departments that do not contain the job_id ST_MAN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).